# Difference between "programmatic" and "programmable"

Tags: differences, vocabulary

Are "programmatic" and "programmable" the same? Can they be used in place of each other freely? For example, "programmable control" and "programmatic control".

Comment: As hayhorse indicates in his answer, programmable refers to the potential to be programmed, while programmatic refers to something that actually has been programmed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different.

Programmatic describes something that is the result of a program.

Programmable describes something that can be programmed.

Comment: Can you add some references to online dictionary definitions ?

Comment: They still seem a bit confused to me. Could you please elaborate on that by giving examples?